# will not find out about the read has no value as a specific use

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Excuse my bad English.

This is how I have come into a problem as do that when the use of a question on the side so it will not find out if the questions and answers match with the database.

indicate in any way any reply as I should have back.

I've tried to debug it and it will not give me anything.

I would like that it just found out about this answer can be found in the database and this question fits with the answer.

on my opgaver.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = conn1;

    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 opgaver.id, opgaver.rigtigsvar, opgaver.overskift, opgaver.svar1, opgaver.svar2, opgaver.svar3, opgaveLydefiler.mp3 FROM opgaver INNER JOIN opgaveLydefiler ON opgaver.overskift = opgaveLydefiler.navn ORDER BY newid()";

    conn1.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        LabelOverskift.Text = reader["overskift"].ToString();
        AudioMp3.Attributes["src"] = "/lydefiler/opgaver-filer/" + reader["mp3"] + ".mp3";
        LabelAsk1.Text = reader["svar1"].ToString();
        LabelAsk2.Text = reader["svar2"].ToString();
        LabelAsk3.Text = reader["svar3"].ToString();

        Session["opgaverid"] = reader["id"];
    }


    conn1.Close();

}   
protected void ButtonSvarAsk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    //hvilke af radiobutto er valgt?
    string svar = "";
    if (ButtonA.Checked)
    {
        svar = "A";
    }
    else if (ButtonB.Checked)
    {
        svar = "B";
    }
    else if (ButtonC.Checked)
    {
        svar = "C";
    }

    string rigtigsvar = svar;
    string opgaveid = Session["opgaverid"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rigtigsvar", rigtigsvar);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", opgaveid);

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM opgaver WHERE Id = @id AND rigtigsvar = $rigtigsvar;";

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        conn.Close();

        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = conn1;

        string id = Session["id"].ToString();

        cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE brugere SET point = point + 1 WHERE Id = @id;";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

        conn1.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn1.Close();

        LabelSucces.Text = "Du fik 1 point!.. Tillykke!!";
    }
    else
    {
        LabelError.Text = "Det er forkert!.. øv Øv!";
    }
}
```

on my opgaver.aspx

```
<div class="pi-section-w pi-section-white piTooltips" style="min-height:500px;">
<div class="pi-section pi-padding-bottom-80">
        <h1>
            Opgaver til dansk
        </h1>
        <h2><asp:Label ID="LabelOverskift" runat="server"></asp:Label></h2>
        <p><asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
        <p><asp:Label ID="LabelSucces" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
    <audio controls="">
        <source id="AudioMp3" runat="server" src="" type="audio/ogg">
        Din browser understøtter ikke lydfilen.
    </audio>

        <div style="padding:5px 10px;">
            <p><asp:RadioButton ID="ButtonA" runat="server" GroupName="1" /> <asp:Label ID="LabelAsk1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <p><asp:RadioButton ID="ButtonB" runat="server" GroupName="1" /> <asp:Label ID="LabelAsk2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <p><asp:RadioButton ID="ButtonC" runat="server" GroupName="1" /> <asp:Label ID="LabelAsk3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSvarAsk" runat="server" Text="Svar" CssClass="btn pi-btn-blue" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM opgaver WHERE Id = @id AND rigtigsvar = $rigtigsvar;"
```

Could this be a misspell? Shouldn't it be

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM opgaver WHERE Id = @id AND rigtigsvar = @rigtigsvar;"
```

Comment: It does not come forward and say to use that you have done it right or wrong.

Comment: if you debugger never get's to ButtonSvarAsk_Click-method, make sure there's an event handler connected to it

Comment: Ohhh its work now.. i have add "ButtonSvarAsk_Click" on my button.